# JSON in Flex. "Access of undefined property JSON"

Tags: apache-flex, flash, json

I am trying to parse JSON in an Adobe Flex app, using http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2006/03/28/tutorial-using-json-with-flex-2-and-actionscript-3/'>This Tutorial

Unfortunately, Flex Builder 3 is flagging a "Access of undefined property JSON" error on the line

`var arr:Array = (JSON.decode(rawData) as Array);`

I don't know what it wants, since I included the import line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to download, install, and reference the utility library that contains the JSON routines. See http://labs.macromedia.com/wiki/index.php/ActionScript_3:resources:apis:libraries#corelib

Did you do that, and include it in your project?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the new location for corelib: https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib  (as of Feb. 2011 when I'm writing this)

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code

```
var arr:Array = (com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(rawData) as Array);
```

instead of

```
 var arr:Array = (JSON.decode(rawData) as Array);
```

Dont forget to import below package
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

its working good for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use native JSON-api supported by Flash Player 11!

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#methodSummary

Answer (score -1):

Check your input file for validity. GI=GO.

I would try including in in a HTML page with Firefox + Firebug and seeing if you get a similar error there.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use AIR 3 to get native JSON support.
  http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/08/native-json-support-in-air-3.html

In FlashDevelop 4.0.1 using Flex SDK 4.6.0 and "Flash Player" as the platform, native JSON is not available. I get the “Access of undefined property JSON” error.

I had to switch the platform from "Flash Player" to "AIR" under Project settings.

Comment: -1 • "You have to use AIR 3..." is wrong.  JSON support is also included in the Flash Player 11 (and up) build.  You don't have to switch to an AIR project in order to enjoy the benefits of the native JSON support.  See [JSON Docs in Lang Ref](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html).  Please revise, and I'd be glad to +1 and remove my comment.